# Camel-smpp Issue with SMPPsim

Tags: apache-camel

I am having camel route like as follows.I am using SMPPSim as simulator...

I am facing following issue.....

Failed delivery for exchangeId:  Exhausted after delivery attempt: 6 caught: org.jsmpp.extra.NegativeResponseException: Negative response 0000000b found. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[jms://queue:Error])]]
org.jsmpp.extra.NegativeResponseException: Negative response 0000000b found
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.validateResponse(AbstractSession.java:215)[233:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp:2.1.0.1]
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.java:271)[233:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp:2.1.0.1]
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.submitShortMessage(SMPPSession.java:320)[233:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsmpp:2.1.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.smpp.SmppProducer.process(SmppProducer.java:146)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-smpp:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:114)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:284)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:109)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:99)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[89:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-07-15]

If anybody helps...that is greatful..

Comment: Have you searched the internet about what - Negative response 0000000b found means?

Answer (score 1):

Error Code 0x0000000B means ESME_RINVDSTADR Invalid destination address.   Most likely you are passing a blank value in the destination address field for JSMPP.  I faced this error in the past and the destination address was incorrect